# Severe graphics and application problems after update

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade

I wanted to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 with the built-in upgrade-feature. but during the upgrade my pc stopped working.

When I restarted my PC Ubuntu starts OK, but with many errors (many apps don't work and some graphic-errors). I try to upgrade again to 12.04, but I can't, because my Ubuntu identifies itself as 12.04.

I tried to upgrade with the cd-setup but this also doesn't work. What should I do, if I don't want to reinstall the whole system?

Answer (score 2):

I would do a fresh install. if possible try backing up everything you want to keep, unless you have dual boot with a shared partition. If you already tried a live-cd as an upgrade tool, my guess you'll have to do a fresh install.

Comment: Don't forget to check the answer that helped.

Comment: in addition to my comment it helps close threads so that it doesn't appear to be open to further suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, czifro thank you for your tip. This is how i partly solved the Problem:
i used the live-cd of 11.10 and chose "upgrade" (in this case it was a downgrade, but ubuntu always calls it upgrade). Now my ubuntu identifies itself as 11.10 again and it is able to upgrade to 12.04. But before i am going to upgrade there is another Problem: now my mice (both internal touchpad and external mouse) and my external Keyboard Do Not work. The only hud working is my integrated (in the notebook) Keyboard. These three devices only Do Not work in ubuntu, in grub and in Windows 7 there is nö Problem with them. What should i Do?

Answer (score 0):

I had a few issues after upgrade ... the trick was to run the update manager and install any updates it found (which was a LOT).

After doing that a couple times everything calmed down nicely.